# Error in AWS ElasticBeanStalk python 27 application that was running fine

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had an py27 application running on aws ElasticBeanStalk for over a year. Recently it stopped working. So I tried to redeploy. During redeploy I got the following error in the logs:

Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] 
command failed with error code 1:
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py 
New python executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 
Not overwriting existing python script /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python 
(you must use /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27)

Can somebody tell me where I will find /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python? How can I change it to
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you redeployed, you opted into the latest beanstalk version, which uses a different AMI than the one originally used. If you're familiar with the concept of [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) then you're probably looking to add a file like this:

.ebextensions/python.config:
`ln -s /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python`

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: Tal,

I created a folder .ebextensions at my application root and added file python.config with the line below in it:

map:     ln -s /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python

I deployed the application but still got error:

command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py New python executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 Not overwriting existing python script /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python (you must use /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27) 

As I continue to investigate would appreciate help with things to try. 

Thanks.

Comment: Did you commit the file? Also check the log to see that this was executed upon deploy

Comment: Tal,
Thanks. I had tried to 'update' a broken app rather than create new ebs app so probably the python.config was ignored. Now I created a new ebs app with above python.config. The error messages have changed so looks like it was read. 
I am attaching the error message and my requirements.txt below. 
Please let me know if you can think of things to try.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: requirement.txtFlask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
boto==2.32.1
bson==0.3.3
itsdangerous==0.24
py==1.4.23
pytest==2.6.1
pytz==2014.4
requests==2.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2

Comment: [Instance: i-36f77380] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py New python executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 Also creating executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python Installing setuptools, pip...done. Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python27 --use-mirrors has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Explicit uses of --index-url and/or --extra-index-url is suggested.

Comment: Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.10.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1)) Running setup.py (path:/opt/python/run/venv/build/Flask/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests' warning: no .

Comment: (another error message). Your requirements.txt is invalid.

Comment: Hello,

An update: I was able to solve the issue. My bson lib version in requirements.txt wasn't available for download on the pypi (went mising). So I used the next version in my requirements.txt. I also removed the .ebextensions folder that I had created and everything started working again.